# How to find last egde connecting vertices from traversing two disjoint, equinumerous sets of vertices

Tags: algorithm, set, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal

Given two disjoint, equinumerous (of size `n`) sets (called `0` and `1`) with values from `1` to `2n` I have to find the last edge (pair of vertices) formed by a specific traversal.

Traversal algorithm:

- start from value `1` (it does not matter in which set this value is)
- connect it with first, free value from opposite set (first relative to actual value, so if current value is equal to `3`, then I will check `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, ..., `2n - 1`, `2n`, `1`, `2`)
- repeat second step

Example:

```
n = 5
Set "0": { 1, 2, 4, 8, 9 }
Set "1": { 3, 5, 6, 7, 10 }

Traversal path:
1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 8 -> 10 -> 2 -> 6 -> 9 -> 7

Answer -> 9 and 7
```

I was able to solve this problem with `2 * (1 + 2 ... + n) = 0(n^2)` complexity. But I believe that there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `O(nlogn)`

- First sort both array and set `current = 1`
- Now find which array contains 1, as you have to start with value 1
- Now search the position of the `current value` in the opposite array(nearby) using binary search in O(logn)
- Find the difference of the left and right nearby values and change current value to the value which results smallest difference
- Of course set all the values visited which you already worked with. So that you dont work twice with the same value
- So the overall complexity is **O(nlogn)**

**4th step Elaboration:**

Suppose your current value is in `array a` and you are searching in `array b`...

```
current value = 5  
b = { 2 , 3 , 8 , 10}  
            ^
```

if you do binary search in array `b`, the position you will get is `2`. So now -

set `current value = 8` and mark 8 as visited.
Now do `step 2 and 3` in `array a` and so on ...

**Update :**

A sample C++ implementation:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int>right_a,right_b;
// Using union_find algorithm to find the next available value(which is not visited)
int find1(int x)
{
    if(x==right_a[x])
      return x;
    right_a[x]=find1(right_a[x]);
}
int find2(int x)
{
    if(x==right_b[x])
      return x;
    right_b[x]=find2(right_b[x]);
}
int main()
{
    int i,j,k,l,m,n=5;

    int a[]={1, 2, 4, 8, 9};
    int b[]={3, 5, 6, 7, 10};

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        right_a.push_back(i);
        right_b.push_back(i);
    }

    int cur=1,work_with;
    if(a[0]==cur)
    {
        right_a[0]=1;
        work_with=0;
    }
    else
    {
        right_b[0]=1;
        work_with=1;
    }

    printf("%d",1);
    int cnt=1;
    while(cnt<2*n)
    {
        if(work_with==0)
        {
            // find first relative to actual value in array b
            int ind=lower_bound(b,b+n,cur)-b;
            if(ind==n)
              ind=0;
            ind=find2(ind);
            int next=ind+1;
            if(next==n)
                next=0;
            right_b[ind]=right_b[next]; // making current value visited
            printf(" -> %d",b[ind]);
            cur=b[ind];

            work_with=1;
        }
        else
        {
            // find first relative to actual value in array a
            int ind=lower_bound(a,a+n,cur)-a;
            if(ind==n)
              ind=0;
            ind=find1(ind);
            int next=ind+1;
            if(next==n)
                next=0;
            right_a[ind]=right_a[next]; // making current value visited
            printf(" -> %d",a[ind]);
            cur=a[ind];

            work_with=0;
        }
        cnt++;
    }
    printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ali! I have a problem with understanding of the 4th step of your algorithm. If you can show me a sample implementation (I am familiar with C++ (and STL), Python, Java and pseudocode) or just elaborate on this step (small example should clarify this in my mind) I will be really happy :)

Comment: I edited the answer about 4th step...
I'm a little busy right now, so can't give you the implementation..
If you find it difficult to implement then i will give the implementation later